# Two different text styles in placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is it possible to have two styles in an input box placeholder?

Here is an example of what I'm looking for: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OH9A.png

Comment: do you want the user to be able to delete the "Tag" text ?

Comment: Yes I would like the placeholder to disappear.

Comment: It's not possible only with the `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options would be use a background image that has the text, or use an element overlay with th text or put the text behingd the imput.

Here's a simple demo that places the text behind the input and hides it on focus

http://jsfiddle.net/GRsQc/1/

Comment: Yes this seems to work just fine. Thanks for your help charlietfl.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to position text over the input field, obviously it can be styled as pre your example and hide the text using jquery or javascript when the text field is selected. If you want to provide some code I can be more specific.