# How to style an individual word in Placeholder attribute

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

Is there a way to style an individual word in a placeholder attribute?  My marketing department is asking me to bold the first word in the placeholder. Below is the image marketing would like to achieve:

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your questions, has been answered, previously.
Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12868750/5650475

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This placeholder attribute is a property takes raw text as an input,...it can't be styled...only option here it so use some javascript with your input box..,

**check this out might come in handy**

```js
function handle(){  
 if(document.getElementById("input").value==""){
   document.getElementById("tag").style='opacity:1';
 }
}

function handle2(){
  if(document.getElementById("input").value!=""){
   document.getElementById("tag").style.display="none"
 }
  else{
    document.getElementById("tag").style.display="inline-block";
  }
}
function handle3(){
  document.getElementById("tag").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("input").focus();
}

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('mouseout',handle,false)
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('keyup',handle2,false)
document.getElementById("tag").addEventListener('click',handle3,false)
```

```css
input_container{
  position:relative;
}
#input {
  position:relative;
  width:400px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  padding:0;
  margin:none;
}
#tag{
  display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
  border-radius:4px;
  left:2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_container">
  <input id="input">
  <div id="tag"><span style="font-weight:bold">Search</span> vendors,healthcare..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this way is better.

```js
var state = true;

function hideText() {
  var info = document.querySelector('#search').value;
  if (state) {
    document.querySelector('#text').style.visibility = "hidden";
    state = false
  } else if (!state && info == "") {
    document.querySelector('#text').style.visibility = "visible";
    state = true;
  }
}

function clickText() {
  document.querySelector('#search').focus()
}

document.querySelector('#search').addEventListener('focus', hideText);
document.querySelector('#search').addEventListener('blur', hideText);
document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('click', clickText);
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 10px;
  --color-main: rgb(66, 157, 199);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
}

#search {
  width: 50rem;
  height: 5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid var(--color-main);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input id="search" name="busqueda" type="text">
    <label for="busqueda" id="text"> <strong>Hello</strong> World!</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Style the `<label>` instead of input

```css
label{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}
label input{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  SEARCH
  <input type="search" placeholder="vendors, healthcare...">
</label>
```

Comment: Nice one! Together with JavaScript you can achieve the look and feel of an input without the label - just make the label disappear on focus

Comment: @Michael why? judging by the design, only the gray text disappears. Makes "UX"-sense.

Comment: Sure would, but I'd prefer (just for me) the label disappear, too. +1'd your answer btw as I like your solution to the question and my thoughts were in a different way - but yours is better.

Comment: @Michael Regarding serious UI concerns there's often a need to always keep the input label text visible cause an input's loses meaning and purpose  as soon the `placeholder title` disappears. Thx

Comment: Yes, the more I think about it, the better your answer gets for me. I've been thinking in terms of responsive mobile design, where the space for the user's input would matter - that's why I would have made the label disappear,  but I like the UX argument

Comment: @Michael yes. Labels + design + UI + UX matters. I built recently for a project: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/d7Lpmg34/1/ for the exact same reason: to **preserve the label** in a meaningful and attractive way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with the placeholder tag, but you can make it appear this way by styling elements, as per this example:

> html

```
<div><input type="text"/> <span>First</span> <span>name:</span></div>
```

> javascript

```
$("span").css({"position": "absolute"})

$("span:first").css({"color": "green" })
$("span").eq("1").css({"color": "red", "left": "44px" })

$("input").on("focus", function(){

$("span").hide();

})

$("input").on("blur", function(){
if ($(this).val() == "") { $("span").css("display", "inline-block")}
})

    $("span").click(function(){

    $("span").hide()

    })
```

> css

```
div {position: relative}
input {color: green}

span {left: 10px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgd2e/1/

Comment: this is a nice approach using jquery